# Smartsheet API to Collect Payment Information

Tags: python, payment-processing, smartsheet-api

Has anyone used Smartsheet API to capture payment data?
I work with a Property Management group that will be accepting applications via Smartsheet's web form. Those applications require a deposit. My city uses NIC Inc. (EGOV) as their payment gateway. Apparently there are a couple of reports (one daily, one @ each transaction) that will give us all the information about the payments but it would be best if Smartsheet could collect the information automatically.

I am very new to coding but I have good resources to call on to implement suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to write data to your sheet using the Smartsheet API (we even have a [Python SDK](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk) to help with that).
Your next step should be to determine whether the [eGov API](https://www.egovstrategies.com/section/subsection.php?structureid=30) supports the exporting of the data that you want to bring into Smartsheet.
Assuming both APIs do what you need, then the person writing the scripts can automate them by using a cron job or a webhook (if eGov API supports it).